# Mismatch between primary and secondary y-axis ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a dataset with 3 columns: `DEPTH`, `TVD_SCS_interp`, `Gamma_ray`. I want to create a plot of DEPTH (on the left y-axis), TVD_SCS_interp (on the right y-axis) vs Gamma_ray (x axis). I tried to plot both TVD_SCS vs Gamma_ray and DEPTH vs Gamma_ray to make sure whether the ticks' positions are correct (I expected lines to overlap each other since their Gamma_ray values are the same), but there is inconsistency between the alignment of the DEPTH and corresponding TVD_SCS_interp values as shown in the image below.

Here is my code:

```
DEPTH = df.DEPTH     
TVD_SCS_interp = df.TVD_SCS_interp     
GAMMA_RAY = df.GR_N 

# Create an array for the x-axis
x = np.array(GAMMA_RAY)

# Create a figure and two axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 165))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1, width_ratios=[0.4])

# Create subplots within the custom grid
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
# Create a second y-axis on the right side
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Plot 'DEPTH' data on the left y-axis
ax1.plot(x, DEPTH, color='b', label='DEPTH')
ax1.set_ylabel('DEPTH', color='b')
ax1.set_ylim(2180, 4076.5)

# Plot 'DEPTH_TRU' data on the right y-axis
ax2.plot(x, TVD_SCS_interp, color='r', label='TVD_SCS_interp')
ax2.set_ylabel('DEPTH_TRU', color='r')

top = df.loc[df['DEPTH'] == 2180, 'TVD_SCS_interp'].values[0]
bottom = df.loc[df['DEPTH'] == 4076.5, 'TVD_SCS_interp'].values[0]
ax2.set_ylim(top,bottom)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

# Set labels and title
ax1.set_xlabel('GAMMA_RAY')
ax1.set_title('Two Y-Axes Plot')

# Show legend
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

**How can I create a plot with a secondary y-axis whose tick labels are related to the first y-axis?**

Here is some sample data:

```
{
    "DEPTH": [4398.1, 4398.2, 4398.3, 4398.4, 4398.5, 4398.6, 4398.7],
    "TVD_SCS_interp": [
        4200.23,
        4200.98,
        4201.4,
        4202.12,
        4202.89,
        4203.3,
        4204.21,
    ],
    "Gamma_ray": [150, 155, 161, 145, 165, 137, 153],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using [regression](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) to estimate a best-fit relationship between dual isodimensional axes (e.g., two `y` axes)

### → To display *aligned* bivariate data w.r.t. a shared identical independent variable (`x`)

For example, below I have generated a roughly extrapolated expansion upon the sample data you provide - where two monotonically increasing variates in the y-dimension share identical value in the   dimension but different scale & rate of change in , hence necessitating an estimation (i.e., regression analysis) for optimally dividing and assigning their tick values to ensure alignment of the two data.

```py
import math
import random

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
num_points = 37

linear_values = np.linspace(4200.0, 4500.0, num_points)

# Some noise is introduced to complicate the linear spacing 
noise = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, num_points)
secondary_values = linear_values + noise

# Ensure the secondary y-axis values always have a positive rate of change
for i in range(1, len(secondary_values)):
    if secondary_values[i] <= secondary_values[i - 1]:
        secondary_values[i] = secondary_values[i - 1] + np.abs(noise[i])

data = {
    "DEPTH": np.arange(4398.1, 4398.1 + (num_points * 0.1), 0.1),
    "TVD_SCS_interp": secondary_values,
    "Gamma_ray": random.choices(range(130, 170), k=num_points),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

DEPTH = df.DEPTH
TVD_SCS_interp = df.TVD_SCS_interp
GAMMA_RAY = df.Gamma_ray

# Estimate the relationship between DEPTH and TVD_SCS_interp
# using polynomial regression (least squares fit)
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(DEPTH, TVD_SCS_interp, 1)

### Plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8), dpi=150)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1, width_ratios=[0.4])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(
    GAMMA_RAY,
    DEPTH,
    color="b",
    marker="o",
    markersize=6,
    linestyle="-",
    linewidth=3,
    alpha=0.5,
    label="DEPTH",
)
ax1.set_ylabel("DEPTH", color="b")
depth_max = math.ceil(max(DEPTH))
ax1.set_ylim(4398, depth_max)

# Set limits for the secondary y-axis based on the relationship
# & adjust tick locations for the secondary y-axis based on the primary y-axis
ax2.set_ylim(4398 * slope + intercept, depth_max * slope + intercept)
ax2_ticks = [y * slope + intercept for y in ax1.get_yticks()]
ax2.set_yticks(ax2_ticks)

ax2.plot(
    GAMMA_RAY,
    TVD_SCS_interp,
    color="r",
    marker="o",
    markersize=2,
    linestyle="--",
    label="TVD_SCS_interp",
)
ax2.set_ylabel("DEPTH_TRU", color="r")

ax1.set_xlabel("GAMMA_RAY")
ax1.set_title("Two Y-Axes Plot")

ax1.legend(loc="upper left")
ax2.legend(loc="upper right")

plt.grid(True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.6, alpha=0.4)
plt.grid(True, which='minor', color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.2)
plt.minorticks_on()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

results in:

[image: Plot with aligned dual y-axes tick labels]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I solved the my issue using the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440474/matplotlib-twinx-wrong-values-on-second-axis. However, I also wanted to display only every 10m tick labels. I figured out this and published the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77172306/how-to-align-secondary-y-tick-positions-to-primary-y-axis-and-change-frequency-o?noredirect=1#comment136072601_77172306