# How to align secondary y tick positions to primary y axis and change frequency of secondary y ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ticker

I have a dataset with 3 columns: `DEPTH`, `TVD_SCS_interp`, `Gamma_ray`. I made a plot of DEPTH (on the left y-axis), TVD_SCS_interp (on the right y-axis) vs Gamma_ray (x axis) with the following code:

```
# Sample data (replace with your actual data)
data = {
        'DEPTH': [100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240],
        'TVD_SCS_interp': [50.5, 60.2, 70.3, 80.7, 90.2, 100, 100.15, 120.9],
        'GR_N': [150, 150, 120, 130, 140, 130, 110, 100]
    }
ax1.plot("GR_N", "DEPTH", data = df, color = "#00be00").
ax1.set_ylim(bottom_depth, top_depth)
    
ax20.set_ylim(df.loc[df['DEPTH'] == bottom_depth, 'TVD_SCS_interp'].values[0], df.loc[df['DEPTH'] == top_depth, 'TVD_SCS_interp'].values[0])
```

I realized that secondary y (TVD_SCS) values do not correctly align with the corresponding primary y (DEPTH) values to the end of data points. This was because of data in `ax2` has a different scale and arbitrary increments than `ax1`'s (where it has linear scale). For example, TVD_SCS value 100.15 was not in front of DEPTH value 220 like in the data I provided).

So, I found a partial [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzV56.png) to this problem and achieved the following result:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

def depth_to_tvd(depth):
    return df.loc[df['DEPTH'] == depth, 'TVD_SCS_interp'].values[0]

ax1.plot(df.Gamma_ray, df.DEPTH, color='b', label='DEPTH')
ax1.set_ylim(top_depth, bottom_depth)

ax2.set_ylim((ax1.get_ylim()))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=10))
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax2.set_yticklabels([Text(0, yval, f'{depth_to_tvd(yval):.2f}') for yval in ax1.get_yticks()])
```

[image]

I want to get tick positions for whole numbers (not decimals like in the picture) on the secondary y axis, and you see although I used

```
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=10))
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

it did not help me.

Could anyone help me to correctly align whole "TVD_SCS" values at the corresponding position of "DEPTH" and making **the frequency of "TVD_SCS" ticks 10** as the primary y axis?

Comment: Does `ax2.set_yticks([50, 60, 70, 80, 90])` produce the expected output?

Comment: No, they do not align with 'DEPTH' values.

Comment: Try setting the range on the secondary axis to see if you get any closer to what you'd like to produce: `ax2.set_ylim(40, 120)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to correctly align the secondary y axis values related to primary y axis, and displaying only 10th tick labels (2610, 2620, ..). In my dataset, `TVD_SCS_interp` has no or very few whole numbers corresponding to `DEPTH`. So, in
order to change the major tick positions to every 10 m and minor tick positions to every 1 m, I created whole values using `np.arange` function.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

try: #if there is no DEPTH value for top_depth, find it by interpolation
    s = np.ceil(df[df['DEPTH'] == top_depth]['TVD_SCS_interp'].values[0])
except:
    s = np.ceil(Int_TVD_SCS(top_depth))
try: #the same here
    e = np.floor(df[df['DEPTH'] == bottom_depth]['TVD_SCS_interp'].values[0]) + 1
except:
    e = np.floor(Int_TVD_SCS(bottom_depth))
    
TVD_SCS_whole = np.arange(s, e)
```

Since, we get ticks from the primary axis and change its labels in the secondary axis, **we need to get the corresponding `DEPTH` values for those whole `TVD_SCS`'s (every 1.0 and 10.0 ticks)by interpolation**:

```
Int_MD = interp1d(df["TVD_SCS_interp"], df["DEPTH"])
MD_interp = Int_MD(TVD_SCS_whole)
#Make MD_interp and TVD_SCS_whole a dataframe
....
#Join that to actual dataset
df = df.merge(df_MD_interp, on=['DEPTH','TVD_SCS_interp'], how='outer')
df = df.sort_values(by='DEPTH')
```

I will manually assign major and minor tick positions using `ticker.FixedLocator())` function. Thus, I find major and minor tick values by the following code:

```
df['TVD_SCS_interp_mod'] = df['TVD_SCS_interp'] % 10
# Find major and minor ticks using vectorized operations
y_ticks_major = df.loc[df['TVD_SCS_interp_mod'] == 0, 'DEPTH'].tolist()
y_ticks_minor = df.loc[(df['TVD_SCS_interp_mod'] % 1 == 0) & (df['TVD_SCS_interp_mod'] != 0), 'DEPTH'].tolist()

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax20 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax201 = ax20.twinx()
ax1.plot("GR_N", "DEPTH", data = df, color = "#00be00", linewidth = 1, zorder=10, antialiased=True)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
def depth_to_tvd(depth):
    return d.loc[d['DEPTH'] == depth, 'TVD_SCS_interp'].values[0]

ax20.set_ylim(bottom_depth, top_depth)

ax201.set_ylim((ax20.get_ylim()))
ax20.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(y_ticks_major))
ax20.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(y_ticks_minor))
ax201.set_yticks(ax20.get_yticks())
ax201.set_yticklabels([Text(0, yval, f'{depth_to_tvd(yval):.0f}') for yval in ax20.get_yticks()])
ax201.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(y_ticks_major))
ax201.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(y_ticks_minor))
#other plot functions (tick length,...)
...
```

The final plot is:

[image]